# my Ajax call does not hit breakpoint in controller action

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, debugging

hi i have following code in my controller httppost action where i am trying to save applicant detail in my database using ajax in mvc entity framework

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<JsonResult> SaveApplicantDetails()
    {
        try
        {
            CareerApplicant ca = new CareerApplicant();
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[0];
                ca.ResumeLink = UploadFile.UploadDocFile(file, "uploads");
            }

            ca.Email = Request["email"].ToString();
            ca.ContactNo = Request["contact"].ToString();
            ca.Name = Request["name"].ToString();
            ca.CareerID = Convert.ToInt32(Request["careerid"].ToString());
            db.CareerApplicants.Add(ca);
            db.savechanges();
```

and following is my ajax call

```
 $("#btnSave").click(function () {
        if ($("#form1").valid()) {
            var fd = new FormData();
            var files = $("#flResume").get(0).files; // this is my file input in which We can select multiple files.
            fd.append("name", $("#txtName").val());
            fd.append("email", $("#txtEmail").val());
            fd.append("contact", $("#txtContact").val());
            fd.append("careerid", $(this).attr("careerid"));

            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                fd.append("Uploads" + i, files[i]);
            }
            alert("hit1");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveApplicantDetails", "Careers")',
               contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: fd.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("suc called");
                    if (data == "Success") {
                        alert("suc called inner");
                        alert("Thanks for your intrest, You applied successfuly.");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("suc failed called");
                        alert("Error Occured while saving data.");
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            alert('the form is not valid');
        }
    });
});
```

when i am trying to hit breakpoint in my controller it doesnt hit...i dont know why..seeking help here thank you

Comment: it is expecting your formdata to carry `anti-forgery token` but you are just sending custom data.. Instead just `serialize form` and send it through `formdata` as in `var fd = new FormData($("#flResume").get(0));`

Comment: still not hitting the breakpoint...without it i can get to know what mistake i am doing...i just need breakpoint to b hit when i debug inside controller action

Comment: Do you have your ajax call in separate `js` file or in `cshtml` file?.. Any console errors? What does network tab says?

Comment: i have my ajax method in the html file in view folder, it says fd does not exist in current context

Comment: You are getting `alert(hit1)` atleast?

Comment: i have my ajax call in index.cshtml file in view folder only where my html controls are...and i dont get any error msg that is the problem...my page gets an roundtrip without doing anything

Comment: yes i am getting alert (hit1)

Comment: but then what does it do i have no clue...m just learning this..this is my first project i am working on

Comment: Do you have `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` inside your `form`? Or else just remove `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` from controller and try!!

Comment: yes that was creating the problem... i removed that and it worked....sorry i forgot to mention it here due to excitement of working of my code lol...thank you for your effort bro :) now i am also able to send an notification email on the applicant's email id .cheers

Comment: Just a point to note.. `AnitforgeryToken` is needed whenever you post your data to controller, because of security reasons to avoid CSRF attack and you should add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` inside your `form`, so that when `form` is serialized this token will also be serialized and hence the controller will know that the request came from valid `client`.. Just read of `AntiForgeryToken` in `MVC`.. **DO NOT REMOVE THAT**.. That is not the actual solution...

Comment: how about adding a model class with all the validation and use AntiForgeryToken to validate all the inputs by the user?

Comment: That will be the most good approach...

Comment: thank you brother for the guidance :)

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just removed  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] from my controller action and it worked ..thank you guruprasad for making efforts :) really appreciate

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> SaveApplicantDetails()
{
    try
    {
        CareerApplicant ca = new CareerApplicant();
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[0];
            ca.ResumeLink = UploadFile.UploadDocFile(file, "uploads");
        }
        ca.Email = Request["email"].ToString();
        ca.ContactNo = Request["contact"].ToString();
        ca.Name = Request["name"].ToString();
        ca.CareerID = Convert.ToInt32(Request["careerid"].ToString());
        db.CareerApplicants.Add(ca);
        int res = await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        if (res > 0)
        {
            string mailto = Request["email"].ToString(); /*ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendMailTo"].ToString();*/
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                EmailMessage EmailMsg = new EmailMessage();
                string MessageString = EmailMsg.ReadFile("MailFormat.html");
                Career c = db.Careers.Where(x => x.Id == ca.CareerID).FirstOrDefault();
                MessageString = MessageString.ToString().Replace("{Title}", c.Title);
                MessageString = MessageString.ToString().Replace("{dateTime}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                MessageString = MessageString.ToString().Replace("{UserName}", ca.Name);
                MessageString = MessageString.ToString().Replace("{Email}", ca.Email);
                MessageString = MessageString.ToString().Replace("{Contact}", ca.ContactNo);

                EmailMsg.SendMailMessage(ca.Name, "Applicant Person detail.", MessageString, mailto);
           }).Start();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Json("Error");
    }
    return Json("Success");
}
```